# Evaluate DataFrame datetime.datetime objects without iteration

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime, filter

As I have seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas) it is not interesting to iterate DataFrames if you want your code to be scalable...

So I am importing a .xlsx spreadsheet with a 'Date' column that pandas automatically recognizes as datetime.datetime format.

*Here is an example of the code:*

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.read_excel('Sheet.xlsx')

df['Date'][0].month == 1

Output:
True
```

If I try `df['Date'].month` it gives `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'month'`

Whereas the `df['Date']` input returns a Series with all datetime.datetime objects.

So my question is how can I get a Series with all booleans for a tested month without having to iterate all rows one-by-one?

I have also considered [those methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values) to select rows with given value(s), but to be sincere I am stuck with this because I`m filtering objects.

Could also be wrong but I believe it would be much more efficient if I would have to iterate only for the month number rather than by each row...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month.html), if extract attributes from column is necesary `.dt`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce')

mask = df['Date'].dt.month == 1
```

Or [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for compare:

```
mask = df['Date'].dt.month.eq(1)
```

Comment: Hey it worked!!

Well... not right away as it got `AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values` error.

But I only needed to `df['Data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Data'], errors='coerce')` before using .dt accessor and everything worked fine.

Thank you!

Comment: @Azgrom - Interesting, most time if datetimes are read from excel no converting necessary ;)